# Strange thing with linked list

Tags: c++

So I was doing this exercise on linked list. It's a very easy exercise but I noticed that something strange going on. The exercise asked to create a node with a name, an age and a average variable for a student. All nodes have to be in a linked list.
This code works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node // Node for linked list
{
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
        float average;
        Node* next;
    
        Node(){}
    
        Node(string n, int a, float av) // I'm using a constructor cuz I'm lazy
        {
            name = n;
            age = a;
            average = av;
            next = NULL;
        }

};

int main()
{
bool isRunning = true;
Node* head = NULL;
Node* temp = NULL;

string n;
int a; 
float av;

while(isRunning)
{   
    cin >> n >> a >> av;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new Node(n, a, av);
    } else {
        temp = head;
        
        while(temp->next != NULL) // works like this
        {
            temp = temp->next;  
        }
        
        temp->next = new Node(n, a, av);
    }
    
    cout << "continue? (1 = yes / 0 = no): ";
    cin >> isRunning; 
}

cout << "Students: " << endl;
while(head != NULL)
{
    cout << "Name: " << head->name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << head->age << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << head->average << endl << endl;
    head = head->next;
}
return 0;
}
```

so this code works with the while loop with condition `temp->next != NULL` and them `temp->next = new Node(n, a, av)` but if in the condition I use try `temp != NULL` and then `temp = new Node(n, a, av)` it doesn't work.

So the non working code is the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node // Node for linked list
{
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
        float average;
        Node* next;
        
        Node(){}
        
        Node(string n, int a, float av) // I'm using a constructor cuz I'm lazy
        {
            name = n;
            age = a;
            average = av;
            next = NULL;
        }
    
};

int main()
{
    bool isRunning = true;
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* temp = NULL;
    
    string n;
    int a; 
    float av;
    
    while(isRunning)
    {   
        cin >> n >> a >> av;
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node(n, a, av);
        } else {
            temp = head;
            
            while(temp != NULL) // works like this
            {
                temp = temp->next;  
            }
            
            temp = new Node(n, a, av);
        }
        
        cout << "continue? (1 = yes / 0 = no): ";
        cin >> isRunning; 
    }
    
    cout << "Students: " << endl;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << head->name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << head->age << endl;
        cout << "Average: " << head->average << endl << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So probably the problem is the way I'm "creating" the new node at the end right?

Comment: In your non-working code, although you create a new node, it never gets linked to the other nodes (ie you never set the next pointer in the head node or any other node to point at the new node).

Comment: Lazy programmers make some of the best programmers. And if being lazy gets you to use constructors, all hail laziness. Though in this case I'd also accept [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: Suggestion: Get even lazier and use a debugger to step though the code so you can see what the program is really doing. The debugger is probably the number 2 programmer productivity tool right behind the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to append a node to your existing list, you need to:

1. Find the last node in the list, let's call it `l`.
2. Set `l->next` to a newly-created instance of `Node`.

The first version of your code does exactly this, whereas the second just creates an orphaned `Node`.  The fact that you assign this to `temp` doesn't achieve anything.